# Stop page load after SSH2_EXEC when script is loaded

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

I figured out how to make some shell scripts in my CentOS 6.6 server and run them from a PHP web page. My only problem is that one of those scripts (used to start a game server) doesn't actually stop running. What I mean is if I execute it from a SSH terminal, the script runs and the game server gets launched but it never returns to bash so I can input a new command.

If I want to enter a new command (i.e. to stop the server or exit the terminal) I have to press Ctrl+C.

My problem with this is that the PHP page never stops "loading". After I run the script from the page, the game server starts but the page keeps on loading. How can I avoid this?

I'm thinking I can maybe put a 10 second timer in my shell script and then do some sort of Ctrl+C to tell my PHP script it finished running the script but I don't know if that's possible or How to do it.

Here's the shell script to start the game server:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/user/serverfiles/
./serverstart "$@"
```

And this is how I run it form my site:

```
$ip = '192.168.0.30'; 
$user = 'user'; 
$pass = 'password'; 

$connection = ssh2_connect($ip); 
ssh2_auth_password($connection,$user,$pass);

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'stop');
$errorStream = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
stream_set_blocking($errorStream, true);
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
echo "Output: " . stream_get_contents($stream);
echo "Error: " . stream_get_contents($errorStream);        
fclose($errorStream);
fclose($stream);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
./serverstart "$@"
```

by

```
./serverstart "$@" &
```

Comment: Still the same with `./serverstart "$@" &`